# Why does $\sum_{j,k\geq 0}\frac{(j+k)a^{j+k}}{j!k!}=\sum_{l=0}^\infty \frac{l(2a)^l}{l!}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, soft-question

I notice that $$\sum_{j,k\geq 0}\frac{(j+k)a^{j+k}}{j!k!}=2ae^{2a} = \sum_{l=0}^\infty \frac{l(2a)^l}{l!}.$$

Is there a simple intuitive explanation why these two should have the same sum, or is it more or less a coincidence?

To be clear, I'm not wondering how to prove they are the same, but wondering if it is part of a general pattern of replacing sums of $j,k$ by single-index sums and getting the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an instance of a general pattern. It doesn't always work out as nicely as it does here, but the principle is: Cauchy-product. You rearrange the sum so that you sum the terms with $j+k = m$ in a group:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{j,k \geqslant 0} \frac{(j+k)a^{j+k}}{j!k!} &= \sum_{m=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=0}^m \frac{1}{k!(m-k)!}\right)ma^m\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{k}\right)\frac{ma^m}{m!}\\
&= \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{m2^ma^m}{m!}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks